# Showing Ajax on Colorbox Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have external links that returns html so I use AJAX to call them, after which I want the html to be rendered in a colorbox window.

```
function appAjax(url) {
  alert(url);
  var response = null;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      response = data;
      appWindow(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus);
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}

function appWindow(data) {
  //alert(data);
  $.colorbox({html: data, width: 1100, height: 500});
}
```

The first link loads the html properly, but the following links are not returning anything, an error appears in the console saying undefined is not a function.

Any light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that this will only work for pages on your own domain or pages on other domains that have explicitly allowed this?

Comment: yes. I'm aware. the first link I click works, the subsequent links fails to load, returning "undefined is not a function" error